# Header throws error only when included in header but not in cpp file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include, declaration, eigen

I have some header files from a [library](https://github.com/cdcseacave/openMVS), if i include them in my .h file they throw some errors(see below). However if i include these headers in my .cpp or .hpp files everything compiles well. What could be the reason behind this? In this specific case what is different between including a file in a header and a cpp file?

In the library i'm tryin to include, the proposed pattern is that you have an application in a cpp file where you include the headers. So i am not sure if i am re-defining things or ti create some circular inclusion.

here's my header file:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H
#include "myLibrary.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>


class myClass{
private:

    std::vector<myLibrary::type> var1;

public:
    myLibrary::type2 var2;

    void method1();
    void method2();    
};

#endif //MYHEADER_H
```

And the .cpp file:

```
#include "myheader.h"
void myClass::method1(){...}
void myClass::method2(){...}
```

if i do an hpp or cpp file like this, all is fine though:

```
#include "myLibrary.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>


class myClass{
private:

    std::vector<myLibrary::type> var1;

public:
    myLibrary::type2 var2;

    void method1();
    void method2();    
};

void myClass::method1(){...}
void myClass::method2(){...}
```

in CMake i use the command add_library to make a library out of my code with the following line which results in error:

```
add_library(target myheader.cpp myheader.h)
```

I know i am supposed to provide more information but i am kinda lost on what to show in this situation. Here's a piece of the error, in case it's useful. When i google i see some bugs related to that specific eigen class, so if that's the case i am more interested on finding a workaround for this rather than a clean fix.

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrixBase.h:30:64: error: type/value mismatch at argument 4 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Derived, class Scalar, class OtherScalar, bool EnableIt> struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base’
                                         EigenBase<Derived> >
                                                            ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrixBase.h:30:64: note:   expected a constant of type ‘bool’, got ‘Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrixBase.h:143:94: error: type/value mismatch at argument 4 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Derived, class Scalar, class OtherScalar, bool EnableIt> struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base’
 typedef internal::special_scalar_op_base<Derived, Scalar, RealScalar, EigenBase<Derived> > Base;
                                                                                                    ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrixBase.h:143:94: note:   expected a constant of type ‘bool’, got ‘Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrixBase.h:144:11: error: ‘Base’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
 using Base::operator*;
```

The rest of the errors i think are caused by this error and specific to the library so i omitted them.

Comment: Showing the minimized files that produce the error and those that don't would probably help reproducing and narrowing down the problem.

Comment: What's the difference between .h and .hpp files?

Comment: @nwp okay added a simple example.

Comment: Please copy and paste, don't paraphrase.

Comment: @molbdnilo You mean the content of the actual files? I felt like that would make the question harder to read and follow than it already is.

Comment: I'm still lost. What do I have to do to get your error?

Comment: It only happens with the specific library. I already made an issue but there's no answer: https://github.com/cdcseacave/openMVS/issues/269

You basically have to build library files, include the MVS.h in your header file, implement it in .cpp file and make it a library or executable

My motivation to ask here is to get a general insight about what could be the reason rather than finding an exact solution.

Comment: Please, read [SO: MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have to prepare a minimal example which reproduces your issue (with as less code as possible). Please, present this as code example (so that anybody can copy/paste it to his/her side and reproduce your issue on its own). Often it happens while preparing such example the author finds the error on its own. In this case, you may present your experiences as [SO: self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the insight, i was desperate as making a minimal example was going to be quite complicated and long. But on my way trying i figured out the error like you said after many sleepless nights :]

Apparently it was about the order i include things and the namespace issues in some headers.

Though the answer may be a bit superficial as i couldn't give much information in the question. Should i still make an answer or just delete the question as it doesn't give much information to others.

Comment: "Should i still make an answer or just delete the question as it doesn't give much information to others." This, you may decide on your own. Regarding namespaces: I've learnt in quite a number of SO answers that using `using` in headers is dangerous. As you state the order of includes is relevant, I believe this might be the case for you (your sources) as well (but I might be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i was including some other header which used "using" statements for some namespaces before the library i mentioned. When i removed those statements from my header and moved that include under the include of my library header everything worked like a charm.